# SparkSQL - got duplicate rows after join & groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes with columns as shown below.
Note: Column `uid` is **not a unique key**, and there're duplicate rows with the same uid in the dataframes.

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet(args(0)).drop("sv")
val df2 = spark.read.parquet(args(1))

scala> df1.orderBy("uid").show

+----+----+---+
| uid| hid| sv|
+----+----+---+
|uid1|hid2| 10|
|uid1|hid1| 10|
|uid1|hid3| 10|
|uid2|hid1|  2|
|uid3|hid2| 10|
|uid4|hid2|  3|
|uid5|hid3|  5|
+----+----+---+

scala> df2.orderBy("uid").show

+----+----+---+
| uid| pid| sv|
+----+----+---+
|uid1|pid2|  2|
|uid1|pid1|  1|
|uid2|pid1|  2|
|uid3|pid1|  3|
|uid3|pidx|999|
|uid3|pid2|  4|
|uidx|pid1|  2|
+----+----+---+

scala> df1.drop("sv")
  .join(df2, "uid")
  .groupBy("hid", "pid")
  .agg(count("*") as "xcnt", sum("sv") as "xsum", avg("sv") as "xavg")
  .orderBy("hid").show

+----+----+----+----+-----+
| hid| pid|xcnt|xsum| xavg|
+----+----+----+----+-----+
|hid1|pid1|   2|   3|  1.5|
|hid1|pid2|   1|   2|  2.0|
|hid2|pid2|   2|   6|  3.0|
|hid2|pidx|   1| 999|999.0|
|hid2|pid1|   2|   4|  2.0|
|hid3|pid1|   1|   1|  1.0|
|hid3|pid2|   1|   2|  2.0|
+----+----+----+----+-----+
```

In this demo case, everything looks good.

But when I apply the same operations on the production large data, the final output contains **many duplicate rows (of same `(hid, pid)` pair)**.
I though the `groupBy` operator would be like `select distinct hid, pid from ...`, but obviously not.

So what's wrong with my operation? Should I repartition the dataframe by `hid, pid`?
Thanks!

-- Update
And if I add `.drop("uid")` once I join the dataframes, then some rows are missed from the final output.

```
scala> df1.drop("sv")
  .join(df2, "uid").drop("uid")
  .groupBy("hid", "pid")
  .agg(count("*") as "xcnt", sum("sv") as "xsum", avg("sv") as "xavg")
  .orderBy("hid").show
```

Comment: can you justify `many duplicate rows (of same (hid, pid) pair)` with an example?

Comment: Are you sure that they are really true duplicates and not some rogue symbols in `hid` and `pid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have found the root cause.

Maybe this is caused by AWS S3 consistency model.

The background is, I submitted 2 Spark jobs to create 2 tables, and submitted a third task to join the two tables (I split them in case any of them fails and I don't need to re-run them).
I put these 3 `spark-submit` in a shell script running in sequence, and got the result with duplicated rows.
When I re-ran the last job just now, the result seems good.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I think that there are problems with the data, not the code. Of course there shouldn't be any duplicates if `pid` and `hid` are truly different (I've seen some rogue Cyrillic symbols in data before).

To debug this issue you can try and see what combinations of 'uid' and `sv` values represent each duplicate row.

```
df1.drop( "sv" )
  .join(df2, "uid")
  .groupBy( "hid", "pid" )
  .agg( collect_list( "uid" ), collect_list( "sv" ) )
  .orderBy( "hid" )
  .show
```

After that you'll have some start point to assess your data. Or, if the lists of `uid` (and 'sv') are the same, file a bug.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll look into my data first.